# is it possible to get s3 ObjectSummary of specific key?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

From the boto documentation, and examples in stackoverflow, all examples use:

```
all_matches = Bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key)
```

and than loop over the result set for a full math

```
match = filter(lambda x: x.key == key, all_matches)
```

isn't there a method that does this directly?

Comment: The answer is : NOT YET.
This is the boto3 source code.
https://github.com/boto/boto3

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you want an `ObjectSummary` instead of an `Object`? If you aren't searching through a list, there isn't any reason to go for an `ObjectSummary` since they both will perform the same `HEAD` request.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# Get Full Object
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
obj = s3.Object('key')

# Get Object Summary. Performs the same request as .Object
objsum = s3.ObjectSummary('bucket-name', 'key')
```

Comment: I only need the meta data.
the code you supplied is wrong - it creates "disconnected" objects - they aren't connected to the server

Comment: The first time you try to access a value that isn't loaded, it will attempt to load by making a HEAD request.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `print(objsum.key)` it should get you the key.